# Update Specific fields in a document record using MONGODB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb.So in sql to update the specific fields the query is

In sql::

```
update students set marks = 95, grade = 'A' where _id = '1234';
```

In mongo shell ::

```
db.students.update({_id:'1234'},{"$set":{"marks":95,"grade":'A'}},{multi:false});
```

Using mongotemplate , how can we acheive this. I have tried using the following code for single field update and it is working.

```
String uniqueId = student.getSection() + "#" + student.getRollNo();
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(uniqueId));
    Update update = Update.update("marks", student.getMarks());
    logger.info("[Updating the Student marks using the id=]["+uniqueId+"]");
    UpdateResult result =  mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, Student.class);
```

But how we acheive to update grade also using mongo templete?
**Note** :: I want to update specific fields in the document , not replacing the entire document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Call [.set(key, value)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Update.html#set-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)

```
Update update = Update.update("marks", student.getMarks()).set("grade", student.getGrade());

//Alternative
Update update = new Update().set("marks", student.getMarks()).set("grade", student.getGrade());
```

Comment: Hi @Valijon, thanks for the answer. It is working. But if i want to update the multiple fields without disturbing the existing fields, how can i acheive through pojo object ?. Is there any function like( saveorUPDATE like present in hibernate) ?

Comment: @user11790395 Give an example please